# how to pass jwt token to swaggerBundle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

i have react 16.4.1 in my app and I am using swaggerbundle. My problem that I use jwt token all my back services.

```
 const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
url: "http://myservice.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json?"+jwtToken,
validatorUrl : false,
dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
deepLinking: true,
presets: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
  SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
],
plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
],
layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})

window.ui = ui
}
```

so where should i pass the jwt token to make my swagger work properly. 
Thx

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "pass the jwt token"? Is your Swagger file itself (`url`) is protected by a JWT token, and the question is how to configure Swagger UI to send this token when loading the `url`? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: when I do REST call on myservice.swagger.io, I need to pass the jwt token to get access the data. I add the jwtToken at the end of myservice url and it can get the swagger json from the myservice, but it could not access the data. so when I use the swagger api, it will show the 403 error.